# Self Managed JAAS Enable Apache Kafka + AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka

I've been trying to trigger my lambda with Self managed jaas enable apache kafka(deployed/running in EC2 Instance). Both the resources Lambda and EC2 instance of which my jaas enable kafka is deployed/running is under vpc network and having same security group they both have the same inline policy as below :

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
            "ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface",
            "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
            "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Resource": " arn:aws:ec2:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT_ID>:instance/<instance-id>"
    }
]
}
```

Following steps are used add trigger to lambda :

1. In the Lambda function, select the Configuration tab. In the Designer panel, choose Add trigger.
2. In the dropdown, select Apache Kafka:
3. For Bootstrap servers, add each of the two instances private IPv4
   DNS addresses with port 9092 appended.
4. For Topic name, entered the topic created in kafka.
5. For preferred batch size inserted partition count and starting
   position values set Latest.
6. For VPC, VPC subnets, VPC security groups kept the same as of Ec2 instance.

Choose Add.

But still after doing these i received error as
**Last processing result: PROBLEM: Connection error. Please check your event source connection configuration.**

Comment: I don't know what "self managed JAAS" means, but you need to add SASL JAAS config to the Kafka client properties, and that's not related to the IAM policy

Comment: @OneCricketeer Self managed jaas enable apache kafka here it means that i used my own version of apache kafka in my EC2 instance having JAAS enabled. I'm not using MSK which is managed by AWS.  Since AWS has new trigger event which is KafkaEvent i want to trigger my lambda using it. It's possible to trigger my Lambda without JAAS enabled kafka trigger event.

Comment: If your cluster is not exposing a PLAINTEXT listener port, then you need to setup JAAS credentials in all clients, wherever they're running

Comment: @OneCricketeer My cluster is exposing PLAINTEXT port, as my other lambda's is able to write on it. But, Since because of this new event trigger (kafka trigger/event) my lambda is fail to get triggered by kafka and received error  Last processing result: PROBLEM: Connection error. Please check your event source connection configuration.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm unable setup JAAS credentials for kafka trigger/event

Comment: Does your producer use credentials? If not, then your error is just a networking problem. If you can't use credentials in a trigger, then that's an AWS issue, and you should open up a support ticket with them. Or  use something else that can use it to trigger the lambda. Otherwise, did you configure the "secret key" section shown here? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-self-hosted-apache-kafka-as-an-event-source-for-aws-lambda/

Comment: @OneCricketeer Earlier I tried with the link provided by you but it use public subnet and our client need to use private subnet as all my resources, producer and consumer are on private subnet and on same vpc network and credentials my producer did use credentials and able to ingest but the consumer/lambda trigger Kafka event use credentials from secret manager. But still it didn’t work.

Comment: @Mr.Nobody did you find any resolution? I tried with BASIC Auth also, with SASL_PLAINTEXT using AWS Secret manager. But still, this is not working. Here is the link: [SASL_PLAINTEXT](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/06/aws-lambda-now-supports-sasl-plain-authentication-for-functions-triggered-from-self-managed-apache-kafka/)

Comment: @Rocky Balboa After connecting with AWS Support they said that currently their system doesn't support tls/jaas connection managed by user/client. So, we moved to plaintext without any authentication.

Comment: @Rocky Balboa you need to check the security group because in my case i saw that security group is having inbound access from kafka broker ip